# Why isn't the java compiler complaining at this:

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac

I have a line of code that is essentially this

```
NameOfAClassOnTheClasspath.
```

The compiler accepts this without an error or even a warning.  I've tried this in eclipse and on the command line.

What on earth can the compiler (javac 1.6) even think this means and why isn't it complaining?

Comment: post the actual code and its context

Comment: It depends on what the next line is.

Comment: Do you mean you wrote this directly under main() method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since whitespace is ignored, something like

```
SomeClass.

staticMethod();
```

Is a perfectly legal way to call

```
SomeClass.staticMethod();
```

(You can replace the method with pretty much any other static member of the class)

e.g. an inner interface of another interface:

```
Map.

Entry<Integer,Integer> x; // Declares a Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>
```

Of course it's pretty terrible coding style, unless you're breaking lines that are too long to fit on the screen, and in that case you should indent the rest of the line.

Comment: Yes, this is it.  The next is line is
   logger.log("some logging message);
where logger is a non-private static member of class NameOfAClassOnTheClasspath.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that the DOT is a binary operator, so it takes a class and a method.

If you wish the ClassLoader to load the class because you do something in the static initialization, then you should consider using Class.forName("YourClass");